# Python : read array in binary file

Tags: python, arrays, binaryfiles

I am currently trying to read an fortran file with python with the following technique

```
with open(myfile, "rb") as f:
    for i in range (0, n):
        s = struct.unpack('=f', f.read(4))
        mylist.append(s[0])
```

But it is very slow for large arrays. Is there a way to read the content of the entire loop in one time and put it to mylist in order to avoid a conversion/append of each item one by one?

Thank you very much.

Comment: If you changed the format string from `'=f'` to `'={}f'.format(n)`, you could read the entire file in with one `struct.unpack()` call.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is what the [`array`](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html) module is for:

```
a = array.array('f')
a.fromfile(f, n)
```

Now you can use the array object like a normal sequence type. You can also convert it to a list if you need to with `tolist`.